# Fusing Multiple Haar Classifiers for face detection

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, haar-classifier

I am trying to segment a video into foreground and background. Assuming that my video has primarily the face, I start with a face detector and use all pixels inside the face detector as a probably foreground seed for GrabCut.

The problem is that at times(in a few frames), the face detector will not detect a face, although a face is definitely there. Specially when the user looks away from the screen and a side profile of the face is visible.

Is there a solution to this?

An obvious answer that came to my mind as well was to use the side profile Haar Classifier, but how do I fuse  both of them? In the sense, at any point of time I should either have the front profile of the face or side profile (or none at all).

I was wondering if there are any sort of associated confidence values with the detected faces and hence I can use the detection from the cascade which gives a more confident detection.

Comment: you could reduce the 'neighbours' param in the cascade-detection(e.g from 3 to 1 or 2). this will reject less faces.

Comment: I tried that, but this gives a lot more false detections, which is not acceptable either, because that spoils the colour models I am training on the detected faces. 
I am working under the constraint that there is only once face in the frame. For selecting amongst multiple faces which are detected, it will be better if I can associate a confidence score with the detections.

Answer (score 0):

there's a (undocumented) overload for CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale():

```
virtual void detectMultiScale( InputArray image,
                               CV_OUT std::vector<Rect>& objects,
                               CV_OUT std::vector<int>& rejectLevels,
                               CV_OUT std::vector<double>& levelWeights,
                               double scaleFactor,
                               int minNeighbors, int flags,
                               Size minSize, Size maxSize,
                               bool outputRejectLevels ) = 0;
```

the rejectLevels should be the confidence values you're looking for

Comment: Alright. Thanks! I just realised that I am actually using the C functions for my detections. That is, I was the using cvHaarDetectObjects instead of detectMultiScale. I will look up if there is a similar overload for cvHaarDetectObjects as well.

Comment: oh, please don't. move your code to the c++ api instead. please !!

Comment: Oh? I shall do that. Any reason you strongly suggest doing so?

Comment: they moved away from the c-api in 2010 already, it's deprecated. also, to my experience, things get fareasier with the c++ one, as you don't have to preallocate result Mats, do manual memory management, etc. also note, that cvHaarDetectObjects can only read haarcascades, while CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale() can read hog or lbp ones, too. newer functionality is only available from c++.